# data is not parsing I want to parse data into dictionary then into array and then iterate it

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

data is not parsing I want to parse data into dictionary then into array and then iterate it and save it to custom array. from JSON structured `{"stores" : [{},{}]}`

Code:

```
Alamofire.request(NEARBY_STORES, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON{ (response) in

        if response.result.error == nil {
            print(response)
      if let dict = response  as? NSDictionary
      { print("dict saved")
        if let stores = dict["stores"] as? Array<AnyObject>
        {
            for items in stores
            {
            let storeName = items["name"] as? String

            let storeCover = items["cover"] as? String

            let minimumOrder = items["min_order_amt"] as? String

            let  storeRating = items["average_rating"] as? String

            let storeSpeed = items["delievery_time"] as? String

            let  storeLogo = items["logo"] as? String


                let shoplist = shopModel(shopName: storeName!, shopBGImage: storeCover!, shoplogo: storeLogo!, speed: storeSpeed!, accuracy: storeRating!, minimumOrder: minimumOrder!)
                self.shopLists.append(shoplist)
                print("PARSED")
```

Comment: post the expected json

Comment: JSON RESPONSE IS GOOD BUT ITS NOT CASTING IT IN DICTIONARY AND THEN INTO ARRAY

Comment: I think something wrong with declaring dictionary and array types

Comment: Don't use NSDictionary, prefers Dictionary (like `[String: Any]` show the JSON, else we can't guess what's wrong.

Comment: Please post the json. Till you post that, we will not be able to guide you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace if let dict = response  as? NSDictionary with if let dict = response.result.value as? NSDictionary and check

Comment: if let stores = dict["stores"] as? Array<AnyObject> pls help me casting that as an array

Answer (score 0):

I usually use SwiftyJSON to do this parse.

```
            if let result = response.result.value {
                let dict = JSON(result)
                print(dict)
                //you can try to print your stores and continue with your logic
                let stores = dict["stores"]

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let dict = response  as? [String,Any]{
    if let stores = dict["stores"] as? [[String:Any]]{
        for items in stores{
            //Do stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Alamofire.request(NEARBY_STORES, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON{ (response) in

    if response.result.error == nil {
        print(response)
  if let dict = response  as? Dictionary<String, Any> ?? [:]
  { print("dict saved")
    if let stores = dict["stores"] as? Array ?? []
    {
        for items in stores
        {
        let itemDict = items as? Dictionary<String, Any> ?? [:]
        let storeName = itemDict["name"] as? String

        let storeCover = itemDict["cover"] as? String

        let minimumOrder = itemDict["min_order_amt"] as? String

        let  storeRating = itemDict["average_rating"] as? String

        let storeSpeed = itemDict["delievery_time"] as? String

        let  storeLogo = itemDict["logo"] as? String


            let shoplist = shopModel(shopName: storeName!, shopBGImage: storeCover!, shoplogo: storeLogo!, speed: storeSpeed!, accuracy: storeRating!, minimumOrder: minimumOrder!)
            self.shopLists.append(shoplist)
            print("PARSED")
```